# Nonlinear, homogeneous Volterra Equation with Positive Kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Suppose we have a homogeneous Volterra equation of the second kind:
$$
x(t) = \int_0^t K(t,s,x(s))\,\mathrm{d}s, \qquad 0\leq t\leq T,
$$
and the sign of $K$ is determined by only $x$ for all $t$ and $s$. A natural conclusion for me is to think is that if a nontrivial solution exists, it must be nonnegative or nonpositive. But for whatever reason, I can't find a direct proof of this claim, which makes me question its validity. For my purposes, I do not need to approximate $x$ and I don't care what it is, just that it has one sign.

Thank you.

Comment: It appears that your conjecture is true (at least) in two cases:  if we have uniqueness of solutions, or if $K$ is independent of $t$ (then we have an IVP: $x'(t)=K(t,x(t))$, $x(0)=0$). In general, I don't know (I would rather look for a counterexample, but I can be wrong).